# Array.prototype.forEach alternative implementation parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

When working on my latest web application and needing to use the `Array.forEach` function, I constantly found the following code used to add support to older browsers that do not have the function built in.

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Mozilla Foundation http://www.mozilla.org/
 * This code is available under the terms of the MIT License
 */
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;
        if (typeof fun != "function") {
            throw new TypeError();
        }

        var thisp = arguments[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in this) {
                fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I fully understand what the code does and how it works, but I always see it copied with the formal `thisp` parameter commented out and having it be set as a local variable using `arguments[1]` instead.

I was wondering if anyone knew why this change was made, because from what I can tell, the code would have worked fine with `thisp` as a formal parameter rather than a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach.length` is defined as `1`, so implementation functions would be more native-like if they had their `.length` property set to `1` too.

http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18

> The length property of the forEach method is 1.

(`func.length` is the amount of argument that `func` takes based on its definition.)

For `func.length` to be `1`, you have to define `func` to only take 1 argument. In the function itself you can always get all arguments with `arguments`. However, by defining the function to take 1 argument, the `.length` property is `1`. Therefore, it is more correct according to the specification.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. I wonder why the length is 1. I guess it's because the second parameter is optional? (I never knew the length of a function was the number of arguments. Neat!)

Comment: @Joshua: Probably, but whatever the specification says is how it is defined, even if there is no clear reason :)

Answer (score -1):

This will iterate through each of the values in the array without iterating over the string equivalent of prototype functions.

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
    if (typeof fun != "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        ...
    }

}
```